# It seems to take far too long to unlock the "Users & Groups" setting on Mojave than was the case for High Sierra

Tags: macos, mojave, login, system-settings, unlock

This has bugged me from the time I did the first upgrade to Mojave (revision 3) under advice not to upgrade from High Sierra when Mojave was first released. I have tried several resets and even a clean install (I'm now on 10.14.6). Compared to High Sierra, it seems to take as long as 3 - 4 minutes to unlock but (without actually having measured it) HS might have only been a minute or so. Even the login at boot time it seems to take longer and I have to type more slowly type in my login than I used too!
I would appreciate please if anyone can provide any suggestion that might help. I have tried already quite a few discussion groups for answers but many refer to other OS's and other situations not related to mine specifically. I can provide more info if needed.

Comment: It took you “a minute or so” to unlock Users & Groups in Preferences in HS?  That’s way to long as well!.  Are you connected to Active Directory or similar?  To which  “discussion groups” are you referring?  Do you have any sort of special login configuration?

Comment: “Discussion groups“ include Apple Community and general google search responses from sites which I don’t now remember.
Don’t know what Active Directory Is, and no special login: just start up, wait for the Apple logo and then the login panel.